# Django: How do I self-refer to a model but ignore common data fields?

Tags: python, django, models, self-reference

Noob question here.

I have a model that represents plots of land that may or may not contain sub-plots, something like this:

```
class Plot(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    address = models.Charfield()
    area = models.DecimalField()
    parent_plot = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='subplots')
```

I would like to avoid common fields when adding a subplot, for instance the address field, as it is the same as in the parent plot. What is the best way to do something like that?

Also, if a plot is composed of subplots, how could I set it up so that the area of the parent plot is the sum of all subareas. If there are no subplots I should be able to imput the area.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It's just an identifier that's stored. You can pick and choose what columns you want returned via selects.

Comment: I think I understand. If working on the admin page, should it set my model fields with 'blank=True' so that I can ignore common fields and get them later linking the to the main plot through a query?

Answer (score 1):

1. > I would like to avoid common fields when adding a subplot, for
   >       instance the address field, as it is the same as in the parent plot.
   >       What is the best way to do something like that?

You could make `address` as a property and change the address model field to `_address`. The property `address` returns the address of the parent if its own `_address` is empty:

```
class Plot(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    _address = models.Charfield(blank=True, null=True)
    _area = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True)
    parent_plot = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='subplots') 

    @property
    def address(self):
        # here, if self.address exists, it has priority over the address of the parent_plot
        if not self._address and self.parent_plot:
            return self.parent_plot.address
        else:
            return self._address
```

2. > Also, if a plot is composed of subplots, how could I set it up so
   >       that the area of the parent plot is the sum of all subareas.

Again, you can turn `area` into a property and make `_area` model field. Then you can do the following...

```
class Plot(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    @property
    def area(self):
        # here, area as the sum of all subplots areas takes 
        # precedence over own _area if it exists or not. 
        # You might want to modify this depending on how you want
        if self.subplots.count():
            area_total = 0.0;
            # Aggregating sum over model property area it's not possible
            # so need to loop through all subplots to get the area values 
            # and add them together...
            for subplot in self.subplots.all():
                area_total += subplot.area
            return area_total
        else: 
            return self._area
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe a good way would be to use inheritance. Create the main plots as parents and define every thing you want in those and whenever a child of a parent is created, specify what stuff the child inherits from the parent. Not sure if that helps

Comment: Could you expand your answer to include some code examples?

Comment: // Create a super Class like this or something similar
public class Plot {
 public static String name;
 public Plot(){
 }
 public String getName(){
  
  return name;
 }
 
 public void subPlot(){
  SubPLot smallPlot = new SubPLot();
 }
}

// then create a sub class like this.
public class SubPLot extends Plot{
 public String name;
 public static Plot importedPlot;
 public SubPLot(){
  // specify all the variables that the SubPlot should have defined 
  // dont forget to specify return methods in the main class
  name =  importedPlot.getName();
 }
}